# How to stop too many requests in web applications?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, security

I am looking for alternative security cautions for Apache web server. I generally work with PHP and MySQL.

For processes like user login, I keep IP address, try count, and last try time in database, so if someone tries more than x times in last n minutes or seconds, I simply block IP address.

When there are a lot of different processes like user login, keeping IP addresses in database does not sound right (because of decreasing performance and a lot to do). I know if you want security, you need to sacrifice some performance but is there a better way to stop users making too many requests? Maybe a module to Apache? Or a lower level caution to server? I am especially trying to avoid unnecessary database work.

I considered using CAPTCHA but using it for every form kills user experience. And using it after x request in n minutes still requires first technique i mentioned.

A cache system might help but i can't see how it prevents a brute force attack or filling up database with garbage. AFAIK it only helps to reading from database (please correct me if i am wrong).

Comment: If you keep in database records only for IPs within the last hour, it will have close to no impact on performance.

Comment: A comment that is much better solution than an answer...

Comment: I removed [tag:dos], partially because you're not talking about a DoS per se, and also because the tag is for Disk Operating System :) Also as already mentioned, DB Logging is probably the correct solution. As a solution against an actual DoS it would fail, because Apache processes would still spin up to begin to handle the request, only to be killed later... This can still overload your server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than @ranty's comment above (which is suitable unless you really have a lot of users at the same time), you could use a memory cache system such as [memcached](http://memcached.org/). It have a nice php interface and is very easy to use.

Dump every login attempt to memcache (using ip address as key and trycount as value, cleared by timespan). It's fast and should not cost too much in performance or development effort.

Pseudo code for this would look like this:

```
$memcache_obj = memcache_connect('memcache_host', 11211);
$ip = $_SERVER('REMOTE_ADDR');
$trycount = memcache_get($memcache_obj, $ip);
if ( $trycount == null ) $trycount=0;
if ( $trycount > 3 ) die('bad user');
memcache_set($memcache_obj, $ip, $trycount++ , 0, 30);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try CloudFlare, protects your website from all kind of bots/hackers. Keep in mind that stackoverflow is for questions about programming and not for questions about security issues or hosting issues.